# Why Ruby documentations refer every class attribute as "object" but not "string" or "Fixnum" or something?

Tags: ruby, documentation

In [the documentations for Ruby Twitter gem API](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter) under the "Instance Attribute Summary", all attributes are listed as `Object` (eg: `http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/User`), but they can be specified more specifically such as `String` or `Fixnum`. Why are they just listed as `Object` instead of more specific types of attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is generated by parsing the description written manually in the source code, and I guess the specification for the class of an argument is optional. When it is particularly not specified, then it appears as the most general case: `Object`.

Comment: Thank you for editing and answering the question!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently wrong with calling it an object, especially since the documentation generator probably doesn't immediately know the type of Object that will be stored in the attribute. A similar issue arises with Sphinx (which does automatic documentation generation for python projects). Sphinx can not know whether a class attribute will have a non-nil value (assuming you're setting it based on something passed to the class initializer) so it tells you the default value of the attribute is `None` (or `nil`).

Answer (score 0):

**rdoc.info** uses the `yard` gem to generate documentation. It is compatible with Ruby's rdoc, and can be extended with tags to inform it of data types and other details that might be handy for users of a project.

Here is a short snippet of documentation from one of my projects that uses `yard`:

```
# Probability of result equalling specific target
# @param [Integer] target
# @return [Float] in range (0.0..1.0)
```

In short it is possible, and quite easy, to have documentation on rdoc.info that specifies data types for params and return values. Not every project does so. Some may have good reason, or alternative approaches for how users are expected to learn correct usage. Many Ruby projects though are simply more focussed on code than documentation. You may find that a project would welcome a conscientious documenter submitting pull requests that add data types to the API descriptions.